# can't redirect after form submission success with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having problem with my code can't redirect after 3seconds here with my code

```
function userpage(){
  window.location = 'userpage.php'; // User Area
}

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(response == 'success')
                        $("#message").html("<p class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</p>");
                        //Redirect after 3second
                        setTimeout('userpage()', 3000);
                else
                    $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Invalid username and/or password.</p>");
            }
        });
```

this should Redirect after 3 second. but it wont

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with your code probably it does not get into the statement  `if(response == 'success')` that set the timeout

if you are familiar with firebug add a break point to the `success` function to see if the code get in there